# Why am I not able to buy applications?

Tags: software-center, proxy, fluendo

I would have liked to buy some software, but the 'For Purchase' category in the Software Center remains desperately empty.

How do I activate the availability of such apps?

Is it possible that I am unable to connect to Ubuntu One because of my proxy ?

Comment: do you want to buy anything in particular?

Comment: I guess regional settings could be the reason - non-free services some times can be limited to USA and Canada only, or something alike.

Comment: No it is not: I could browse a full 'For Purchase' section once with a direct access to the Internet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently I am not able to connect to Ubuntu One behind a proxy...

Comment: I can hardly believe this to be the reason if your web browser and apt-get work.

Comment: Notice that other programs do not work either: Empathy, Second Life, etc.

Comment: still not making sense

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu One has problem with proxies since ages, see this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/387308

It seems to also affect "For Purchase" section in the Ubuntu Software Center. I see software listed there when at home (no proxy) but not at work (with proxy).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Fluendo is the only commercial application available as of yet. Keep an eye on it, as more software should be coming shortly!

Comment: In fact, even Fluendo is not present in the 'For Purchase' section! Is it because I'm 64bits, or because I didn't activate the repositories, or whatever?

Comment: I'm not sure why it isn't showing for you. I'm running AMD64 as well, and I can see it; I also disabled all of my repositories and reloaded and could still see it. What repositories do you have enabled?

Comment: http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu and http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu are enabled, as main universe multiverse and restricted are.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there are not that many applications for sale in the software centre. The infrastructure is there though and definitely more options should be available in 11.04, and possibly in earlier versions as traction builds. For now, you can enjoy the free software available in the official channels and through [ppas](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Flaunchpad.net%2Fubuntu%2F%2Bppas&ei=ZFnpTIT-I4O78gbM0_SZCQ&usg=AFQjCNGnIv9IyYJB0I33nLfqmm-zm1tOBw&sig2=N_1UniWnd9S5BkGZIZUBsg).

Answer (score 2):

The "For Purchase" section is filling up, albeit very slowly. Apparently a [puzzle game](http://www.techdrivein.com/2010/11/brukkon-puzzle-game-is-now-available.html) is now available (I can't find it in there, but that's probably because I'm using 64-bit Ubuntu).

As for the steps, simply find an app for purchase, then click "Buy". A window should pop up, asking you to create an account or log in.